# NSFileManager doesn't work without admin privileges

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I'm working on a macOS app (distributed outside the Mac App Store) where I download some files from the Internet, create some folders in the `applicationSupportDirectory` under the `localDomainMask`, and write those files to the folders created, using the NSFileManager class.

The app works well when it's running in an admin user account, but it doesn't when the account doesn't have admin privileges (for example, if I use it as a guest user).

How can I make the app ask for admin privileges so NSFileManager doesn't throw permissions related errors?

Comment: You are tackling this wrong. An application, running as any user, can write into that users application support directory (the app should create its own sub directory in there). If your app fails due to permission errors then it is writing somewhere it should not. Check exactly where your app is writing, the permissions on the folders, etc. Test in a newly created user account if needed. If you can't find the issue edit your question to show exact paths, permissions, etc. and someone will probably help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've checked it and actually it fails only when writing under the `localDomainMask`, when the user is not an admin (I've updated the first paragraph). It shouldn't write there, indeed, if the user is not an admin, so my question remains: how can I make the app ask for admin privileges so NSFileManager doesn't throw permissions related errors?

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using `localDomainMask` rather than `userDomainMask`? The latter is the current user’s Application Support (or a sandboxed location), either of which you should always have write access to; IIRC `local` is the one in /Library.

Comment: That's a really good question that I've already shared with my team after confirming that writing to `userDomainMask` is alright even without admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this then you need to escalate the privilege of your application, or better your application's helper, so that the operation can be performed. There are a number of ways to achieve this; and obviously doing so is not just available to any application, or there would be no security.

A good place to start is Apple's [Authorization Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html).

HTH

Comment: Thanks. This is something I've discovered after asking the question and I plan to take a look at it on Monday. I don't fully understand yet the concept of the helper tool or why I would need one given my context, but maybe I would.